# Attribute packed with C++ and clang

Tags: c++, attributes, clang, pragma

I thought that the double bracket notation was intended to replace `__attribute__((foo))`, but I'm not getting equivalence.

Clang toolchain set for C++14.

```
class [[packed]] test {};
class __attribute__((packed)) test2 {};
```

`test` has a warning about unknown attributed `packed` ignored. `test2` has no warning. If I replace `packed` with a made-up attribute, both give warnings.

What's the best way to pack a struct in Clang?

Comment: The standard attributes - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that the double bracket notation was intended to replace `__attribute__((foo))`, but I'm not getting equivalence.

It's not meant to be entirely equivalent. The double bracket notation is for the C++ standard to introduce attributes with a more or less standard meaning. Those often exist already as compiler specific attributes, but it doesn't mean that all compiler specific attributes have a corresponding standard attribute. So you can't expect `[[packed]]` to be a thing just because `__attribute__((packed))` is.

Nevertheless, the standard does give compilers an option to add custom attributes that use double brackets. But such attributes are usually scoped. In this case, the custom attribute is named `[[gnu::packed]]`. As the name implies, it's vendor specific.